# Name mapping between Chrome policies and Chrome experimental options in Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to set some Chrome policies [listed here](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#top) using [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/).
My problem here is that I don't know how to map the Chromium policy names to the preference names to pass to the Chrome driver in Selenium.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130774/how-to-disable-this-type-of-file-can-harm-your-computer-pop-up/34174633), the policy [SafeBrowsingEnabled](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#SafeBrowsingEnabled) becomes:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
    'prefs', {
        'safebrowsing.enabled': 'false'
    }
)
```

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59491516/disable-all-downloads-with-chromedriver-and-selenium), the policy [DownloadRestrictions](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#DownloadRestrictions) becomes:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
    'prefs', {
        'download_restrictions': 3
    }
)
```

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937319/how-to-use-chrome-webdriver-in-selenium-to-download-files-in-python), the policy [DefaultDownloadDirectory](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#DefaultDownloadDirectory) becomes:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
    'prefs', {
        'download.default_directory': '/path/to/folder',
    }
)
```

But where are these mappings coming from? I was unable to find any documentation about this.

Comment: Optionally, you could use `addArguments()`, and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42530229/1431750) lists the sources. Yes, it's unfortunate that it's not easily found in documentation.

Comment: Thanks but that refers to the command line switches. I am talking about Chrome policies/preferences

Answer (score 0):

I believe the available prefs are here:
https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/common/pref_names.cc