# Selenium: How to start electron app that uses Main.js as argument

Tags: node.js, selenium, electron, appium

Using **appium** or **chromeDriver** am trying to open an Electron app witch is using a Main.js argument.
For example, using CMD, I need to run the following command:

**C:\electronExe.exe Main.js**

my driver set up is as follow:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\seleniumgrid\\electron\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.setBinary("C:\\electronExe.exe");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("C:\\Main.js");
    chromeOptions.setCapability("chromeOptions", chromeOptions);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Each time I run the code I only get the electron default screen, which is:

[image]

I tried almost anything without success (Appium driver, desired capabilities, chromeOptions etc').
Am I missing something here?

Any one knows a good solution for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529853/list-of-firefox-and-chrome-arguments-preferences

Answer (score 0):

Try `chromeOptions.addArguments("app=C:\\Main.js");`

It appears positional arguments aren't supported for some reason ‍♂️