# Change download directory using Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am currently able to reach a web page and click on a "Download" button.
When I do this, the download is launch in the default directory (Download... obviously)

I would like to create a folder on my desktop and download every file by default inside. How can I do? What do I need?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to overwrite the default download directory for your browser. This can be done via configuring the web driver. The [Open Browser](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser) keyword of SeleniumLibrary provides separate parameters for this purpose to both Firefox (`ff_profile_dir`) and to Chrome (`options`).

Additionally you have to enable auto save and other browser configs depending on the specific browser you use.

Note that when working on Windows the path passed needs special attention:

> Please note that if options string contains backslash, example a
> Windows OS path, the backslash needs escaping both in Robot Framework
> data and in Python side. This means single backslash must be writen
> using four backslash characters. Example, Windows path:
> `"C:\path\to\profile"` must be written as `"C:\\\\path\\\to\\\\profile"`.
> Another way to write backslash is use Python raw strings and example
> write: `r"C:\\path\\to\\profile"`.

Here is an example that will download the [source of Robot Framework from GitHub](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework) using Firefox and SeleniumLibrary 4.3.0.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Case ***
Download Robot Framework into predefined folder
    Open Browser    https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework    Firefox   
    ...    ff_profile_dir=set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2);set_preference("browser.download.dir", r"C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\Robotframework\\SO_material");set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/zip")
    
    Click Element    //summary[contains(.,'Code')]
    Click Element    //a[contains(.,'Download ZIP')]
    [Teardown]    Close Browser
```

---

The browser parameters set:

1. `browser.download.folderList` was set to `2` where

   > `2` indicates a custom (see: browser.download.dir) folder
   >
   > <sub>Source: [Download Manager preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/Download_Manager_preferences)</sub>
2. `browser.download.dir` is the path to the custom folder. Make sure to pass the path as described in the documentation. I have used Python raw string in this example.
3. `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` is `application/zip` which means that any downloaded zip will be saved without prompting for download location.

You can find links to lists of Chrome and Firefox arguments in this Stack Overflow answer: [List of Firefox and Chrome arguments/preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42530229/3820025).